# Custom UITableview cell accessibility not working correctly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiaccessibility

I have a class which loads a tableview. In this tableview there are 4 sections with 1 row each. Each section row loads different custom cells. I have disabled the accessibility of the custom cells. But enabled the accessibility for the elements in the cell.

With voice over ON, it reads each cell components correctly first. But after we scroll the table with three finger gesture, first or second cell in my table get focused and voice over does not read the elements inside the cell.

Can any body help me in this issue?

Here is the my code for loading the table with custom cell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ if ([indexPath section] == 1  ) 
    {
        static NSString* SettingsTableId = @"HomeAddress";
        pHomeAddressCell = (HomeAddress *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SettingsTableId];

        if (pHomeAddressCell==nil) 
        {
            NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeAddress" owner:self options:nil];
            pHomeAddressCell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        pHomeAddressCell.delegate = self;
        return pHomeAddressCell ;
    }}
```

And in the custom cell "HomeAddress" I have a textview and two buttons.

I have found that this issue is only in devices with iOS below 6

Comment: What do you mean by voice over?

Comment: Please check. I've added the code.

Comment: Is there any cell setup that you're missing after a cell is dequeued for reuse?

Comment: @ Andrew Tetlaw : I don't think so. After all my table works fine. But this issue with voice over exits.

Answer (score 0):

"Storyboards - Prototype Table View Cells Not Working Well With VoiceOver".. at least in iOS 5.

I don't know .. if it is fixed in iOS 6.
The problem seems to be that VoiceOver or the UIAccessibility API is interfering with the loading of the prototype cell. The problem does not occur for static table view cells..

You can check the Open Radar bug reports http://www.openradar.me/search?query=voiceover

Comment: I tested my app in devices with iOS 6 and found this issue is not in iOS 6.

Comment: @user1905823 please, say something… or… accept it, please, if don't have what to say

Comment: @ TonyMkenu You did not specify any solution for my issue. Rather you pointed to a link which shows similar issue. It didn't give the solution either. Thats why I waited.

Comment: Is a iOS 5 bug (storyboard). You must use NIB for tour cell id you want to support 5.0.  For implementation check http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/09/11/voiceover-bug-and-ios-5-tableviews-revisited.html and http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/09/07/prototype-table-view-cells-not-working-with-voiceover.html

Comment: There you have an exemple, also (woldfact)